# .htaccess redirect with variables

Tags: .htaccess

Sorry, I've searched through some related questions/answers and wasn't sure how to proceed.

I want the default index.html file to automatically go to index.html?id=1

Is this possible? If so, could someone help me with the appropriate .htaccess command?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !id=
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.html?id=1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

If the query string does not contain an id parameter, the user will be redirected to the version with the id in the query string. Any other elements of the query string will be maintained.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that didn't work for me.

Comment: Does nothing happen, or do you get an error or wrong redirection?

Comment: It goes to the index page but doesn't keep the variable available in the URL, which seems to cause issues with further include files that are relying on the GET variable from php. Any ideas how to resolve this? Edit: Actually I believe it may be my javascript/jquery functions that are relying on the last segment of the URL.

Comment: So the ?id=1 is not at the end of the URL in the address bar after the redirection?

Comment: It's working now, thank you.  I notice that no file can be used unless it has an id?=x at the end of it.  Is there a fix for that?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I forgot I had that built in as a javascript function to require id?= in the url.  When I turn that off it works as it should. I'm sure you knew it was a problem caused by me. :) Thanks again.